# Button click event cannot fire immdiately

Tags: asp.net

When too many data on my web page, button event click event cannot fire immediately.It may hit after 3 minute later.But it work in less data on web page.Why ? i am beginner in Aps.net web application.Please kindly advice me.
the following picture is my web application form.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/584o0.png)

```
   protected void butPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isAutogenearte = Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["isAutogenearte"]);
        if (isAutogenearte)
        { this.voucherPostignWithAutogenerate(); }
        else
        { this.voucherPostingWithManual(); }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For every click event to fire on server side, the whole data on your web page is uploaded to the server for processing. So more data takes a bit of time to get fully uploaded and then the click event gets fired.

Refer to the [ASP.NET life cycle here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: So , how can i do that? reduce data or any other way?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve when you trigger the button click. But this is the reason for taking a bit extra time for huge data